# How to compare lists inside List<List<some_class>>()?

Tags: c#, list

I have class Sku with properties:

```
class Sku
{
    private string term_name;
    private string sku_name;
    private int sku_qty;

    public string Term_name
    {
        get { return term_name; }
        set { term_name = value; }
    }
    public string Sku_name
    {
        get { return sku_name; }
        set { sku_name = value; }
    }
    public int Sku_qty
    {
        get { return sku_qty; }
        set { sku_qty = value; }
    }
}
```

So I created `List<List<Sku>>`:

```
List<List<Sku>> SplitChosenCopy = new List<List<Sku>>();

List<Sku> skus = new List<Sku>();
skus.Add(new Sku { Term_name = "301", Sku_name = "sku2", Sku_qty = 30 });
skus.Add(new Sku { Term_name = "302", Sku_name = "sku4", Sku_qty = 3 });

List<Sku> skus2 = new List<Sku>();
skus2.Add(new Sku { Term_name = "301", Sku_name = "sku7", Sku_qty = 30 });
skus2.Add(new Sku { Term_name = "302", Sku_name = "sku4", Sku_qty = 3 });

List<Sku> skus3 = new List<Sku>();
skus3.Add(new Sku { Term_name = "301", Sku_name = "sku2", Sku_qty = 9 });
skus3.Add(new Sku { Term_name = "302", Sku_name = "sku4", Sku_qty = 8 });

SplitChosenCopy.Add(skus);
SplitChosenCopy.Add(skus2);
SplitChosenCopy.Add(skus3);
```

How can I compare lists inside `SplitChosenCopy`? For example, by properties `Sku_name` and `Term_name`? Lists `SplitChosenCopy[0]` and `SplitChosenCopy[2]` would be duplicates.

Also such lists are not duplicates:

```
List<Sku> skus4 = new List<Sku>();
skus2.Add(new Sku { Term_name = "301", Sku_name = "sku2", Sku_qty = 30 });
skus2.Add(new Sku { Term_name = "302", Sku_name = "sku4", Sku_qty = 3 });

List<Sku> skus5 = new List<Sku>();
skus3.Add(new Sku { Term_name = "301", Sku_name = "sku4", Sku_qty = 9 });
skus3.Add(new Sku { Term_name = "302", Sku_name = "sku2", Sku_qty = 8 });
```

For example, I want to compare each list from `SplitChosenCopy` with another and get their indexes:

```
foreach (List<Sku> sku in SplitChosenCopy)
{
    //compare list sku with lists in SplitChosenCopy
}
```

Comment: You want to find duplicates?

Comment: Yes, I want to find duplicates

Comment: The order in the list doesn't matter?

Comment: I need to know indexes of duplicate lists.

Comment: The order doesn't matter

Comment: The whole list must contain the same(order doesn't matter), so if one list is just a subset of the other they are not duplicates?

Comment: You defined an equality between two `Sku`. How do you define an equality between two `List<Sku>` ?

Comment: Yes, they are not duplicates

Comment: Lists skus2 and skus3 are the same. They have the same Term_names and Sku_names.

Comment: How is `skus2` and `skus3` are same? they have different sku_name

Comment: Sorry, you are right. skus and skus3 are the same.

Answer (score -1):

Try code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApplication23
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<List<Sku>> SplitChosenCopy = new List<List<Sku>>();

            List<Sku> skus = new List<Sku>();
            skus.Add(new Sku { Term_name = "301", Sku_name = "sku2", Sku_qty = 30 });
            skus.Add(new Sku { Term_name = "302", Sku_name = "sku4", Sku_qty = 3 });

            List<Sku> skus2 = new List<Sku>();
            skus2.Add(new Sku { Term_name = "301", Sku_name = "sku7", Sku_qty = 30 });
            skus2.Add(new Sku { Term_name = "302", Sku_name = "sku4", Sku_qty = 3 });

            List<Sku> skus3 = new List<Sku>();
            skus3.Add(new Sku { Term_name = "301", Sku_name = "sku2", Sku_qty = 9 });
            skus3.Add(new Sku { Term_name = "302", Sku_name = "sku4", Sku_qty = 8 });

            SplitChosenCopy.Add(skus);
            SplitChosenCopy.Add(skus2);
            SplitChosenCopy.Add(skus3);

            var results = SplitChosenCopy.GroupBy(x => x).ToList();

        }
    }
    class Sku : IEqualityComparer<Sku>
    {
        private string term_name;
        private string sku_name;
        private int sku_qty;

        public string Term_name
        {
            get { return term_name; }
            set { term_name = value; }
        }
        public string Sku_name
        {
            get { return sku_name; }
            set { sku_name = value; }
        }
        public int Sku_qty
        {
            get { return sku_qty; }
            set { sku_qty = value; }
        }

        bool IEqualityComparer<Sku>.Equals(Sku  a, Sku  b)
        {

            return  a.term_name.Equals(b.term_name) && a.sku_name.Equals(b.sku_name) && a.sku_qty.Equals(b.sku_qty);

        }
        int IEqualityComparer<Sku>.GetHashCode(Sku obj)
        {
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(obj, null))
                return 0;

            return (obj.term_name + "^" +  obj.sku_name + "^" + obj.sku_qty.ToString()).GetHashCode() ;
        }
    }



}
```